# How to resize multiple images proportionally?

Tags: html, image-scaling

I'm creating a new HTML5 page that has multiple image layers.  The first layer is a background layer that is a full screen image (proportional to the screen size).

The second layer is another image object, which I want to be in a fixed position proportional to the first layer; so if I changed the browser size, both of the 2 images would change size so they are proportional one to each other.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do so?

Comment: what do you mean with "in a fixed position proportional to the first layer"? are they side by side, one inside the other or...?

Comment: The images are one inside the other...Meaning the first layer is the background and the second layer is an object over the background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's suppose we have a "sky.jpg" background image and a "sun.png" image on top of it.

Here's the HTML(5) code:

```
<div id="sky">
<img src="sun.png" id="sun">
</div>
```

And here is the responsive CSS:

```
#sky {
    width:100%; /* width in percentage, so it will adapt to user's screen */
    height:600px; /* here i've set a fixed height, but maybe it's not what you want */
    background:url(sky.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    text-align:center; /* #sun will be centered, not sure it's what you need */
    background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
}
#sun {
    width:15%; /* adjust it to the needed ratio */
    max-width:300px; /* max-width will prevent it from being bigger than the original image */
    min-width:20px; /* min-width is optional */
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/YyQ8R/) (resize the window)

---

Notice the `background-size` property set to `cover` ([more info here](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/)).

It means that the aspect ratio will be preserved [to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can completely cover the background positioning area](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size).

That's why you need an image bigger than most of resolutions (if it's a body-background image).

Other possible values for this property are "contain" and "auto" ([have a look at the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size)).

`background-size:cover;` is [not supported by IE8](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties/#bg11) (that's why we still add `top center` for background positioning) and for some FF versions you'll need a vendor prefix (`-moz-`)

---

Now you can set a width in percentage for #sun, so that it'll keep a ratio to its containing div. To prevent it from becoming bigger than the original size, you can set a `max-width` (and eventually a `min-width`).

The height of the image will auto-adjust in modern browsers.

---

If you don't want a fixed height on #sky, be sure that its container also has a height different than auto (the default value).

For example, if #sky is your page background image, you've to set:

```
html, body { height:100%; }
#sky { height:100%; }
```